# Trouble installing "distribute": NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the Python package "distribute".  I've got it downloaded and it begins to work, but then quits out with the error seen here:

[image]

I have a feeling the solution is somehow related to me going in and defining sys_platform, but I don't have enough of a grasp on what's *actually* wrong to know what to fix.  Thanks for any help!  I'm always blown away at how helpful you all are.

Comment: FYI: In general, it's better to copy and paste the error message over here (in part so future people with this problem can find it more easily.)

Comment: Also: "`Distribute` is a now deprecated fork of the `Setuptools` project." (from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.6.49)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated by Burhan you have to install the `setuptools` package: just use the command:

```
pip install setuptools
```

Most importantly, **do not forget to also uninstall the `distribute` package** (since tools provided by that package are already included by `setuptools`).

Just use the command:

```
pip uninstall distribute
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools); as distribute is now a part of it.